# How can I declare user defined setter, getter method?

Tags: objective-c

guys.

How can I access the variable which I made by `@property` instruction?
I learned that prefix `_` makes possible to access when I use my own getter/setter in an objective-c course.

```
//Person.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Person : NSObject

@property NSInteger age;

// getter
- (NSInteger)age;

// setter
- (void)setAge:(NSInteger)age;

@end
```

```
//  Person.m

#import "Person.h"

@implementation Person

// getter
- (NSInteger)age {
    return _age;
}

// setter
- (void)setAge:(NSInteger)age {
    _age = age;
}

@end
```

But that code gave me errors `Use of undeclared identifier '_age'`.
How can I fix that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add explicit synthesize for ivar, as below

```
@implementation Person
@synthesize age=_age;
```